# Converting PDF with PHP and Imagick not working in live

Tags: php, bash, pdf, imagick

I want to convert all pages of a PDF to JPEG. The PHP-script does what it should locally but fails on our live server.

```
$pdf = Zend_Pdf::load($file['tmp_name']);
echo 'Pages: '.sizeof($pdf->pages).'<br />';

for($pageCounter = 0; $pageCounter < $object->getNumberOfPages(); $pageCounter++) {
    $pagenumber = $pageCounter + 1;
    $currentfilename = $filename . "_$pagenumber.jpg";

    echo $thumbPath.$currentfilename.'<br />';

    echo $file['tmp_name']."[$pageCounter]<br />";

    $return; $out;
    exec("convert -density 250 '".$file['tmp_name']."[$pageCounter]' -quality 60 '$bigPath$currentfilename'", $out, $return);
    var_dump($return); echo '<br />'; echo var_dump($out); echo '<br />';

    exec("/usr/bin/convert -density 16 '/home/data/websites/www/meonline.be/public_html/images/magazines/".$file['name']."[$pageCounter]' -quality 60 '$thumbPath$currentfilename'", $out, $return);
    var_dump($return); echo '<br />';
}
```

I tried to refer to the convert command by explicitly pointing to /usr/bin/convert & /usr/local/bin/convert. I always get 1 (or 127 if i'm pointing to the wrong folder) and the output array is always empty.
All folder as shown exist and have mode 777 set.

Here's a summary of all echoed output:

Full exec command:

```
convert -density 250 '/home/data/websites/www/meonline.be/public_html/images/magazines/HogeschoolPromotorenP-studenten.pdf[0]' -quality 60 '/home/data/websites/www/meonline.be/public_html/images/magazines/big/pLjB9_HogeschoolPromotorenP-studenten.pdf/hogeschoolpromotorenp-studenten_1399449783_1.jpg'
```

First echo `echo 'Pages: '.sizeof($pdf->pages).'<br />';`

```
pages: 1
```

Second echo `echo $thumbPath.$currentfilename.'<br />';`

```
/home/data/websites/www/meonline.be/public_html/images/magazines/thumb/pLjB9_HogeschoolPromotorenP-studenten.pdf/hogeschoolpromotorenp-studenten_1399449783_1.jpg
```

Third echo `echo $file['tmp_name']."[$pageCounter]<br />";`

```
/home/data/websites/www/meonline.be/public_html/images/magazines/HogeschoolPromotorenP-studenten.pdf[0]
```

Fourth echo `var_dump($return); echo '<br />'; echo var_dump($out); echo '<br />';`

```
int(1) 
array(0) { }
```

**UPDATE**

Someone executed my command in the terminal and got the following response:

```
convert: Postscript delegate failed `/home/data/websites/www/meonline.be/public_html/images/magazines/HogeschoolPromotorenP-studenten.pdf': No such file or directory @ error/pdf.c/ReadPDFImage/713.
convert: no images defined `/home/data/websites/www/meonline.be/public_html/images/magazines/big/fs5Jd_HogeschoolPromotorenP-studenten.pdf/hogeschoolpromotorenp-studenten_1399455323_1.jpg' @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/3150.
```

I'm 100% sure that the PDF file exists and the second line complains about the image not being defined, but this command should create them for me.

Comment: Just an idea, but you may have problems using `[0]` in a filename. You may not, but no-one else has any ideas yet so maybe try `_0` in place of `[0]`.

Comment: @MarkSetchell The '[0]' does have it's purpose. It tells Imagick (convert) what page to select from the PDF. The name of the file actually stops after .pdf as far as the command is concerned.

Comment: Are you sure you have the right path to `convert`? Do `which convert` via SSH if you can. If not I believe you can do `$convertPath = 'which convert';` in PHP (but use backticks rather than apostrophes to run it as a console command - backticks won't show up in comments).

Comment: @halfer I could try that, but i'm a intern here and I don't have permission to execute any command outside of my php script...

Comment: So try the backticks trick in PHP, then `:)`. Just tried it on Ubuntu, works fine.

Comment: @halfer: Sorry for the delay. `which convert` actually points to `/usr/bin/convert`

Comment: @halfer I've added a description for the error message that I get when executing this command from bash.

Comment: Great! Do a web search now for "convert Postscript delegate failed" (a good strategy when following up an error is to perform searches of the form '<system/language> <error message>').

Comment: @halfer Postscript delegate failed could mean anything in this context. It seems it could mean that Ghostscript is not installed.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone is looking for an answer, the problem was actually quite simpel.

The local server had Ghostscript installed, the live server didn't...

[Download it here](http://www.ghostscript.com/download/gsdnld.html) and [follow the instructions here](http://wiki.scribus.net/canvas/Installation_and_Configuration_of_Ghostscript#Installing_Ghostscript_as_a_binary_on_Linux.2FUNIX).

In my case, I didn't have access to the commandline on the live server. In that case, check if `/usr/bin/gs` is available (in which case it is installed) with this command from PHP:

```
$return; $out;
exec("/usr/bin/gs 2>&1", $out, $return);
var_dump($return); echo '<br />'; echo var_dump($out); echo '<br />';
```